# run separate build file without breaking dependency or inheriting properties

Tags: java, ant

I'm trying to run a separate build file to create a required jar before running other tasks. I have found two options to do this, neither one satisfactory. The first is using `include`:

```
<include file="$../ProjectName/build.xml" as="PN"/>
```

With this I can run any tasks from the other project build file, but then basic variables like `src` and `bin` cannot have different values for the two files. Ant properties are immutable and apparently global.

The other option, which allows separate property values, is to use the `ant` task:

```
<ant antfile="../ProjectName/build.xml" target="myTarget" dir="../ProjectName" inheritAll="false"/>
```

However, this breaks Ant's dependency checking so that the tasks that depend on this one are always considered stale and rebuilt, leading to unacceptable build times.

Is there any way to run the task in this other build file without clobbering properties or breaking dependency checking? Properties scoped to the current file would do the trick, if there is any such thing.

Comment: I would recommend the `<include>` solution more than the `<ant>` solution. Can you set properties such as `src` and `bin` before the call to `<include>` in your first example? By setting the properties before calling `<include>`, the included build script can't overwrite them.

Comment: That's actually what I'm doing, but then the included script tries to compile the wrong `src` into the wrong `bin`.

Comment: Have you tried the <import> tag? The difference between include and import is that import will 'override' targets and I think properties IF they don't already exist in the main build file. If they do exist in the main build file, the main build takes precedence. I'm not sure if this works the same for properties however. Could be worth a try.

Comment: <import> is even worse- the dependent tasks in the imported file are not renamed with prefixes so that if you call a compile task that depends on an init task, it will perform the init task in the importer instead of the imported.